# How do I ensure python project in VSCODE is using virutal envirnoment and not defaulting to global?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

Having an issue when using `flask` and `flask-wtf`. The issue is that for some reason vscode is defaulting to global rather than the newly created virtual environment. In vscode I will click open folder, create the folder and open it in vscode. Then I'll write my code out and then open terminal in vscode and write: `python -m venv my_venv`, then on the lower left-hand side I will select it as my virtual environment. I then re-open the terminal, write: `pip -V` and the pip it is directed to is the folder directory with my_venv in the path name.

Then I pip install `flask` and `flask-wtf`, check that they are installed with pip list. Everything looks good until I run and vscode says: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask-wtf'`. But when I go to my global environment and where flask is installed too it runs fine. Something is happening to where the python code is recognizing the original flask and not the one in my virtual environment. How do I ensure that the version of flask is the one in the virtual environment and not others installed on my machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are in your terminal in vscode, it should append your command line with your virtual environment name.

So, usually it would show
PS \path

But if your environment is running, it will show
(venv name) PS \path

If it is now showing, be sure to reactivate your virtual environment from your project directory

Comment: Thanks. What I just did was create a new VE in my terminal by writing: ```python -m venv fl_venv``` then a window pops up in VSCODE asking if I want to keep that as my workspace VE, I clicked yes. Then closed the current terminal. Open a new terminal and it says: ```C:\Users\PJ\Desktop\FLASK_PROJECT>c:/Users/PJ/Desktop/FLASK_PROJECT/fl_venv/Scripts/activate.bat```

```(fl_venv) C:\Users\PJ\Desktop\FLASK_PROJECT>```

Then I ```pip list``` shows: ```pip and setuptools. ```

Now what is strange is it works but only when I run from terminal, in output window I get the import errors.

Comment: Appears that there is a big difference between running code in the output window and then selecting from preference>settings>code runner>run in terminal, so that I can run the code in the terminal.